# How to add image alt text in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

How do you add an alt text in xslt? Is it different from xhtml? I've tried the xhtml way
alt="click to go to next image."
but it's not showing up.

-- update
Here is an example of my code:

```
    <xsl:template name="Paging">
    <xsl:if test="$NumPages > 1">
        <div class="productListPaging">
        <xsl:if test="$CurrentPage > 1">
            <div class="productListPagingContent floatLeft">
                <a href="{$PreviousPageURL}">
                    <img class="productListImage" src="App_Themes/skin_{$SkinID}/customimages/BackGreen.png" alt="@alt" />
                        <xsl:value-of select="aspdnsf:StringResource('Mobile.Paging.Previous')" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </xsl:if>
            </div>
       </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: XSLT usually takes XML input and transforms it to (X)HTML or XML or plain text. If the output format is (X)HTML then of course you can create `img` result elements having an `alt` attribute, either as literal result elements or computed with `xsl:element/xsl:attribute` and if and when the transformation result is rendered by a browser it should render it the same way as static (X)HTML. If that does not work for you the show us minimal but complete details allowing us to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the actual XSLT and the input (I just assume you process an xml), you can add the alt-text as any other element-attribute as attribute of the image like this, given that you're in a template matching the image and the image would be named `<image>` in the input:

```
<xsl:template match="image">
<img>
   <xsl:attribute name="alt">
    <xsl:value-of="@alt"/>
   </xsl:attribute>
</img>
....
```

or - in case you're using XSLT 2.0 -

```
<img>
 <xsl:attribute name="alt" select="@alt"/>
</img>
```

or just

```
<img alt="{@alt}"/>
```

(just to have some variety).

**Update:** As part of actual XSLT was provided in OP, mentioned approaches won't work as it's not a template matching an image-element but an image that is added to the output.
I think that the suggestion by Michael Kay given in the comment should work - just to add alt="click to go next" to the image like:

```
<img class="productListImage" 
     src="App_Themes/skin_{$SkinID}/customimages/BackGreen.png"
     alt="click to go next" />
```

Comment: I've tried it. The alt text doesn't seem to appear.

Comment: @user3813162 Not easy to guess, would be helpful if you add at least the relevant part of your xml and possibly the full xslt in your question. Is it already possible for you to write the img with the src and only the alt is missing?

Comment: I updated my question with a sample of my code. I have to add something to the alt text and not leave it blank. It's for accessibility. So in my alt text, i want it to say something "click to go next."

Comment: Did you try `<img src="..." alt="click to go next"/>`

Comment: @user3813162 Just noticed your template - thought you would be matching an image-element in an xml that *has* an alt-attribute (as I mentioned in my answer). As it's kind of a static element, answer provided won't work for you.

Comment: @user3813162 Just updated my answer and suggestion given by Michael Kay should work for you as it's just static text. You really tried it like that? Was the result an empty alt-attribute or was the alt-attribute not written at all?